# Смена селектора на разных блоках js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет. Как по нажатию кнопки "Выбрать" на одном блоке, `data-background-color` стали `smoke` на двух других?
Код сдесь: 
https://codepen.io/romkask/pen/OpdWaW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.btn').on('click', function(){ 
          $('.btn').parent().parent().parent().find('.card-header').attr('data-background-color','smoke');
          $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.card-header').attr('data-background-color','orange');
        })
```